# Calculate result if combobox value changed

Tags: combobox, textbox, vb.net-2010

I have a calculation where I am multiplying the number of panels by the wattage,  and the output is converted to KW. Here is my VB code.

```
Total_watt = ( Watt_In * Npanel)/1000.0
```

If I change DomainUpDown, the result will be generated. If I choose a ComboBox item, the value will not change. I have added few lines to handle the ComboBox, but I am getting the error

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll but was not handled in user code
>   Additional information: Conversion from string "" to type 'Integer' is not valid.

Without the ComboBox code it works fine, but can't get data from the ComboBox.

```
Public Class Solar_Panel
    Dim Total_watt As Double
    Dim Npanel As Integer
    Dim Watt_In As Integer
    Private Sub Solar_Panel_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        RadioButton_Direct_Data_In.Select()
        Watt_In = CInt(ComboBox_PanelWatt.SelectedItem)
        Npanel = CInt(DomainUpDown_NModule.Text)
        Total_watt = (Watt_In * Npanel) / 1000.0
        Label_Tout.Text = CStr(Total_watt)
    End Sub

    Private Sub DomainUpDown_NModule_SelectedItemChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DomainUpDown_NModule.SelectedItemChanged
        Watt_In = CInt(ComboBox_PanelWatt.SelectedItem)
        Npanel = CInt(DomainUpDown_NModule.Text)
        Total_watt = (Watt_In * Npanel) / 1000.0
        Label_Tout.Text = CStr(Total_watt)
    End Sub

    Private Sub ComboBox_PanelWatt_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox_PanelWatt.SelectedIndexChanged
        If ComboBox_PanelWatt.Text = True Then
            Watt_In = CInt(ComboBox_PanelWatt.SelectedItem)
            Npanel = CInt(DomainUpDown_NModule.Text)
            Total_watt = (Watt_In * Npanel) / 1000.0
            Label_Tout.Text = CStr(Total_watt)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error is probably the result of trying to convert the text in the ComboBox to an Integer when no ComboBox item has been selected (and so the Text property is an empty string).

I have several suggestions that I think will improve your class:

1. Use a NumericUpDown control rather than a DomainUpDown as you want to treat its value as a number.
2. Move the code that calculates the total wattage to a Sub so that you only have to code it once.
3. If the ComboBox text is empty, skip the calculation.
4. Use Integer.TryParse to validate the ComboBox text and convert it to an integer.
5. If you allow users to type their own value in the ComboBox, you will need to handle the ComboBox's TextChanged event instead of the SelectedIndexChanged event.

   ```
   Public Class Solar_Panel
       Private TotalKWatts As Double
       Private Watt_In, NPanel As Integer 

       Private Sub Solar_Panel_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
           'The NumericUpDown properties could be set in the designer instead of here
           NumericUpDown_NModule.Minimum = 0
           NumericUpDown_NModule.Maximum = 100
           NumericUpDown_NModule.DecimalPlaces = 0
           NumericUpDown_NModule.Increment = 1

           RadioButton_Direct_Data_In.Select()
           GetTotalWatts
       End Sub

       Sub NumericUpDown_NModule_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles NumericUpDown_NModule.ValueChanged
           GetTotalWatts 
       End Sub

       Sub ComboBox_PanelWatt_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox_PanelWatt.SelectedIndexChanged
           GetTotalWatts 
       End Sub

       Private Sub GetTotalWatts()     
           If ComboBox_PanelWatt.Text = "" Then Exit Sub
           If Integer.TryParse(ComboBox_PanelWatt.Text, Watt_In) Then
               NPanel = CInt(NumericUpDown_NModule.Value) 
               TotalKWatts = NPanel * Watt_In / 1000
               Label_Tout.Text = TotalKWatts.ToString()
           Else
               Label_Tout.Text = "Invalid wattage"
           End If
       End Sub
   End Class
   ```